# What will be the Computational Complexity in terms of order O of the operations shown in the following figure

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, space-complexity, matrix-multiplication

Suppose I have L bits. First, I want to multiply the L bits with L orthogonal codes of length N, and then I want to add all the vectors.

So, first, I have to do a scalar multiplication with a vector and then an addition. Please refer to the figure for more clarity.

What will be the Computational Complexity  (in terms of order O) of the above operations also shown in the figure?
Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: What is your question?  I don't see a question here.  What are your thoughts?  What is the context for this question?  Can you make it useful to others?

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/23593/755

Comment: O(L) additions.